# replace missing with na.locf0

Tags: r

I am trying to fill missing values using zoo package.
my data set is as follows

```
a=c("2017-01-12 00:00:00","2017-01-12 00:03:00","2017-01-12 00:08:00",
    "2017-01-12 00:11:00","2017-01-12 00:14:00","2017-01-12 04:59:00","2017-01-12 05:10:00",
    "2017-01-12 05:30:00")
b=c(NA,NA,1,NA,0,NA,1,NA)
df =data.frame(a,b)
```

to fill the missing's i am trying with

```
df$new = na.locf0(df$b,fromLast=F)
```

O/p should be:

```
a               b   new
1/12/2017 0:00  NA  0
1/12/2017 0:03  NA  0
1/12/2017 0:08  1   1
1/12/2017 0:11  NA  1
1/12/2017 0:14  0   0
1/12/2017 4:59  NA  0
1/12/2017 5:10  1   1
1/12/2017 5:30  NA  1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`na.locf0` (correctly) does not fill in components for which there is no prior value.  If you want to fill in those with some particular value then use `na.fill`.   (In the development version of zoo `na.fill0` will also work.)

```
transform(df, new = na.fill(na.locf0(b), 0))
```

giving:

```
                    a  b new
1 2017-01-12 00:00:00 NA   0
2 2017-01-12 00:03:00 NA   0
3 2017-01-12 00:08:00  1   1
4 2017-01-12 00:11:00 NA   1
5 2017-01-12 00:14:00  0   0
6 2017-01-12 04:59:00 NA   0
7 2017-01-12 05:10:00  1   1
8 2017-01-12 05:30:00 NA   1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

Using `zoo::na.locf0`

```
library(zoo);
library(tidyverse);
df %>% mutate(b = na.locf0(b), b = replace(b, is.na(b), 0))
#                    a b
#1 2017-01-12 00:00:00 0
#2 2017-01-12 00:03:00 0
#3 2017-01-12 00:08:00 1
#4 2017-01-12 00:11:00 1
#5 2017-01-12 00:14:00 0
#6 2017-01-12 04:59:00 0
#7 2017-01-12 05:10:00 1
#8 2017-01-12 05:30:00 1
```

### Option 2

Using `tidyr::fill`

```
df %>% fill(b) %>% mutate(b = replace(b, is.na(b), 0))
#                    a b
#1 2017-01-12 00:00:00 0
#2 2017-01-12 00:03:00 0
#3 2017-01-12 00:08:00 1
#4 2017-01-12 00:11:00 1
#5 2017-01-12 00:14:00 0
#6 2017-01-12 04:59:00 0
#7 2017-01-12 05:10:00 1
#8 2017-01-12 05:30:00 1
```

Explanation: Both `zoo::na.locf0` and `tidyr::fill` fill `NA` entries based on previous entries (by default top down); the last `replace` step replaces leading `NA` values with `0` (since there are no previous entries, these `NA`s cannot be filled).

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
df$new <- na.locf(df$b,fromLast=F, na.rm = FALSE)
df$new[is.na(df$new)] <- 0
df$new
#[1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
```